# Why doesn't decltype(*this)::value_type compile?

Tags: c++, this, type-traits, decltype, is-same

Why doesn't `decltype(*this)` compile? It shows an error message:

```bash
error: 'value_type' is not a member of 'const Foo<char>&'
```

So what exactly is the reason that `decltype( *this )::value_type` does not compile in the below program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename charT>
struct Foo
{
    using value_type = charT;

    std::vector<value_type> vec;

    void print( ) const;
};

template <typename charT>
void Foo<charT>::print( ) const
{
    using Foo_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype( *this )>;

                                   // `decltype( *this )::value_type` does not compile
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< typename Foo_t::value_type,
                                   decltype( std::cout )::char_type > )
    {
        // logic
    }
    else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< typename Foo_t::value_type,
                                        decltype( std::wcout )::char_type > )
    {
        // logic
    }
    else
    {
        static_assert( std::is_same_v< typename Foo_t::value_type,
                                       decltype( std::cout )::char_type > ||
                       std::is_same_v< typename Foo_t::value_type,
                                       decltype( std::wcout )::char_type >,
                       "character type not supported" );
    }
}

int main( )
{
#define IS_CHAR 1

#if IS_CHAR == 1
    using FooChar = Foo<char>;
    FooChar foo;
    foo.vec.resize( 10, '$' );
#else
    using FooWideChar = Foo<wchar_t>;
    FooWideChar foo;
    foo.vec.resize( 10, L'#' );
#endif

    foo.print( );
}
```

What is special about the `this` pointer? Why does removing the reference with `std::remove_reference_t` make it compile? Everything works in the above snippet. But if I replace `typename Foo_t::value_type` with the more readable `decltype( *this )::value_type` it won't compile. So I tried my luck by using `std::remove_reference_t` and managed to come up with the above less straightforward (and less intuitive) solution:

```
using Foo_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype( *this )>;

// and then inside the std::is_same_v
std::is_same_v< typename Foo_t::value_type, /* etc */ >
// ...
```

I know that there are more concise alternatives e.g. `std::is_same_v< Foo<charT>::value_type,` or even `std::is_same_v< charT,` but I find the `decltype` approach more self-explanatory. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: `T` and `T&` are different types, just like `T` and `T*`.  pointers and references don't have the members of the things the point/refer to.

Comment: @NathanOliver The question is why is `decltype(*this)` a reference type when the result of `*this` is not a reference. I found a duplicate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: the result of `*this` *IS* an lvalue (a kind of reference).  That reference can be implicitly converted to something else (usually an rvalue) in many contexts, but a `decltype` is not one of them.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I don't believe that is accurate : https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op#1 lvalue is a value category that is applies a property of an expression. You may be confusing lvalue (the value category) with lvalue references.

Comment: They say it takes a minimum of ten years to learn 33% of this language. Not surprising at all.

Comment: @digito_evo There is a lot of truth to that.  I've been using C++ since ~2000 and I still learn new things every week it seems.  I'm also pretty sure I'll never understand all of the overload resolution rules.  That section of the standard makes my brain hurt just thinking about it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of applying unary `operator*` to a pointer is a reference (lvalue ref) to the pointed at value, not a copy of the pointed at value.  So `decltype(*this)` (or `decltype(*foo)` for any pointer type) will *always* be a reference type.  There's nothing special about `this`.

Comment: I don't think it's that easy. Indirection of a pointer is "lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points" which is not the same as a reference. Edit : See the duplicate.

Comment: An "lvalue" is (just) a kind of reference in C++ (there are other kinds of references as well).

Comment: lvalue references are a kind of reference. An lvalue expression is different. Something can be an lvalue expression without having a reference type. If we have `int i = 0;` the later use of the expression `i;` is an lvalue expression and doesn't use any reference type.

Comment: an `lvalue` *can* be a reference, it doesn't have to be.  in `int foo = 42; foo;`, `foo;` is a lvalue expression.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  No.  In that context `foo` is a declarator, not a reference or an expression.  We're talking about C++ here, not C (which has a totally different meaning for `lvalue`)

Comment: @ChrisDodd `foo` is a declarator in `int foo = 42;`.  It is an lvalue expression in `foo;`.  I have 2 "lines" of code in my comment.

Comment: @NathanOliver: In the expression `foo;` it is an lvalue and has the type `int &` (given the previous earlier declaration).  In a statement like `bar = foo;` it is likewise an lvalue with type `int &` that is implicitly converted into an rvalue (of type `int`) and then stored in `bar` (which itself needs to be a (`something &` type).

Comment: No it doesn't.  `foo` wasn't declared as a reference and `decltype(foo)` is `int`, not `int&`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/330c00696e7cfbaf

Comment: That's because when `decltype` is applied to a *name* (rather than an *expression*) it gives the type of the declarator of the name, not the type of the expression.

Comment: Try changing your example to `test<decltype((foo))>{};` and see what happens -- the extra parens make it an expression rather than a name and you end up with `int &`

Comment: @ChrisDodd `decltype` is a double-duty feature. It can be used to determine the type of an object, and it can determine the value category of an expression, depending on what you give it. It communicates the value category of the the expression by either yielding an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference. The value category of an expression is distinct from the type of whatever it results in. I am as certain that `foo`; is not a reference as I am that it is not a `double`.